# Как узнать имя property внутри сеттера?

Tags: delphi, rtti

Есть абстрактный класс, у класса однотипные `property`, на всех `property`
один и тот же `getter` и `setter`. Мечтаю в этих геттере и сеттере определять
какой `property` в данный момент их вызывает и реагировать соответственно.

```
program rtti;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}
{$R *.res}
{$M+}

uses
  Classes,
  System.SysUtils;

type
  myClass = class( TPersistent )
  private
    Fweight,
    Flength: integer;
    procedure SetInteger(const Value: integer);
    function GetInteger : Integer;
  public
  published
    property weight : integer read GetInteger write SetInteger;
    property length : integer read GetInteger write SetInteger;
  end;

procedure myClass.SetInteger(const Value: integer);
begin
{
  if this is weight then Fweight := Value;
  if this is length then Flength := Value;
}
end;

function myClass.GetInteger : Integer;
begin
{
  if this is weight then Result := Fweight;
  if this is length then Result := Flength;
}
end;

begin

end.
```

Comment: и не мечтайте ... Обращение к свойствам в коде заменяется компилятором на вызовы гетеров и сетеров.

Comment: решение нашлось. indexed properties, но оно мне не нравится

Comment: только хотел предложить именно использовать `Index`, но вы уже нашли это. Других способов,afaik, нет.

Answer (score 1):

Используйте индекс со своим перечислением:

```
type
  TMyEnum = (meWidth, meHwight);
..
  function GetInteger(aIndex: TMyEnum): Integer;
  procedure SetInteger(aIndex: TMyEnum; const Value: Integer);
public
  property Prop[aIndex: TMyEnum]: Integer read GetInteger write SetInteger; default;
```

Свойство с перечислением можно объявить `default`, тогда можно будет к нему обращаться вот так:

```
a := Obj[meWidth];
b := Obj[meHeight];
```

Answer (score 0):

вопрос, конечно,  древний, но подобные вещи весьма распространены. В `delphi` помимо упомянутых свойств с индексным доступом (а-ля `x['width']`) есть ключевое слово `index` при определении свойств:

```
property Width: integer index 0 read getInteger write setInteger;
property Height: integer index 1 read getInteger write setInteger;
```

значение этого индекса передается в качестве первого параметра в get/set методы. В целом подход весьма распространен в VCL, когда речь идет о всяких `top`, `left` и т.п свойствах.
Ваши методы теперь могут иметь следующий вид:

```
function TMyClass.getInteger(idx : integer):integer;
begin
    case idx of 
        0 :  result := FWidth;
        1 :  result := FHeight;
    end;
end;

procedure TMyClass.setInteger(idx : integer; value : integer);
begin
    case idx of 
        0 : FHeight :=  value;
        1 : FWidth := value;
    end;
end;
```

*зы: [тут](http://teran.karelia.pro/articles/item_4506.html) я когда-то писал пост в частности об использовании спецификатора `index` для реализации класса хранения конфига.*